# Upgrade to PHP 5.4 on MAC and remove version 5.3.10

Tags: php, macos, installation

I would tring to update my php version to the version 5.4.

When I'm looking via /usr/local/bin/php -v in the console I see the version 5.4.3 and with php -v it tell me there is the version 5.3.10 installed.

How can I remove the older version?

Comment: Try `which php` to find out, where 5.3 is installed. I guess you used a package manager to install it. Use the same one to uninstall it. However, it's easier to keep it as it is and just call PHP with the full path, or link 5.4 to a path within `$PATH` as `php-5.4` and call it this way.

Comment: The version 5.3.10 is installed at /usr/bin/php.
i dont know which packager i have used. can i check this?

Comment: This way round: No, but I don't think, that there are so many package managers for mac ;) I'm on linux (with `apt` and such), thus I don't know ... Try the default one.

Comment: I'll try it on the normal way. If that not works, then i try it via brew . Thank you

Answer (score 26):

Update:
As of early 2014, you are probably better of installing from http://php-osx.liip.ch/ builds as it contains most extensions. In case you really do need to compile your own, follow the original answer.

Original answer:

Mac comes with a preinstalled php you can easily overwrite.

This is a list of steps I take to update the php I have installed:

Prerequisites:

- Xcode and it's Command line utilities (install form preferences) will give you a gcc compiler to build the php with
- libjpeg, libpng etc. if you want to build with these.

Building and installing php:

- Download the distribution from www.php.net/downloads.php
- Untar the archive and point your console into the location
- Now, having still the original old php installed, run `php -i | head` in the console. What you want is to configure your new php with these flags to ensure you have proper pcre support and everything works just fine.
- In the php source directory you untarred, run the `./configure` script with the flags you just got
- Build php by running `make` and `sudo make install` afterwards. That will actually replace the original php distributed with OS X.

And dont forget to run `make test`...

Ex.: my workflow for building php

```
wget http://url_to/php_source.tar.gz
tar -zxvf php_source.tar.gz
cd php_source/
php -i | head
./configure --prefix=/usr --with-snmp # ... same flags as previous build
make
sudo make install
```