# How to switch to PHP 5.4 using MacPorts?

Tags: php, macports

I need to install PHP 5.4 and for that I thought I could just upgrade my previous php port but version 5.4 was not listed so what I did was:

```
sudo port install php54 php54-apache2handler
```

Then in order to switch to to version 5.4 I did:

```
sudo port select php php54
```

After that I restarted apache with the following:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/apachectl restart
```

But when I `php -v` I get:

```
PHP 5.3.15 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Aug 24 2012 17:45:44) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
```

What I am missing? how can I start using PHP 5.4? Any tip in the right direction much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Have you not considered just using the liip PHP package instead?

Comment: Liip package is not working on Moutain Lion for the moment.

Comment: @GordonM unfortunately I am using Mountain Lion :(

Comment: Try this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11004376/upgrade-to-php-5-4-on-mac-and-remove-version-5-3-10. It looks like a similar issue? It hasn't been accepted, so not sure if it works or not.

Comment: Thanks @DavidC that doesn't use MacPorts but looks like a solution. I will try those steps now, thanks for the link!

Comment: @JordanBelf I'm still using Lion, but the docs say it should work on ML.

Comment: Thanks @GordonM, I tried and it worked! Thanks a lot, I have spent hours on this issue.