# Two versions of php in El Capitan. How do I get rid of one or upgrade the other?

Tags: php, macos, apache, osx-elcapitan

In terminal,

```
php -v
```

gives

```
PHP 5.3.29 (cli) (built: Sep 28 2015 06:33:13)
```

(with imagick installed) but, in the browser (using apache)

```
phpinfo();
```

gives

```
PHP Version 5.5.27
```

(with no imagick installed) How do I resolve this?

I don't want to mess about with php.ini and httpd.conf when I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it. I entered

```
locate libphp5.so
```

into terminal to find paths to the php installations. This outputted

```
/usr/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
/usr/local/Cellar/php53/5.3.29_4/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

I then edited the apache configuration file

```
sudo nano /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

and changed

```
LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

to

```
LoadModule php5_module /usr/local/Cellar/php53/5.3.29_4/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

NOTE : This line will be different for your local installation, copy the value outputted from the locate command above

I then restarted apache with:

```
sudo apachectl graceful
```

Credit to this [solution](https://serverfault.com/questions/428800/how-do-i-tell-apache-which-php-to-use) for the command to find the php installations

Comment: This helped me. I did not have locate so I did
sudo find / -name "*.libphp5.so"

Answer (score 0):

This may be a help to you : [Upgrade to PHP 5.4 on MAC and remove version 5.3.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11004376/upgrade-to-php-5-4-on-mac-and-remove-version-5-3-10)

I would suggest that you work in a virtual setup instead.

like Vagrant: https://www.vagrantup.com/

Also take a look at Homestead: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/homestead

"Laravel Homestead is an official, pre-packaged Vagrant "box" that provides you a wonderful development environment without requiring you to install PHP, HHVM, a web server, and any other server software on your local machine.
"

It will also allow you to keep your configuration if you change machine and/or operating system.